# Spark JDBC and transaction pooling in PGBouncer

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, pgbouncer, spark-jdbc

I am using Spark JDBC DataFramReader to query Postgres DB, the query is executed threw PGBouncer working in Transaction Pooling.

From the second executed query I receive the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: prepared statement "S_1" already exists
```

Is there a workaround for this Error ?

I tried to add `prepareThreshold=0` to the connection string.

Comment: I was using `fetchSize` option in the JDBC, once I removed it, the `prepareThreshold=0` was sufficient

Comment: I found event better solution which allows to work with `fetchSize`. I upgraded the jdbc driver to `org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5`